# Cache manifest not refreshing immediately in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cache-manifest

Im experimenting with a site using the cache manifest on iPhone. Ive added the following to my .htaccess file to prevent the browser caching the manifest file:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access"
```

If I change one of my pages and also add a comment to the manifest file I still need to refresh the page more than once to see any changes.

If I add the site to my iPhone desktop, make a change to the site on the server, and then load the site from the shortcut, I need to manually refresh once to see the change.

How is this sort of problem solved with a real site? Say I made a one page site that functioned like a native app but I wanted it to update itself in the background when an internet connection was available, how could I do this? Would I need to ask my users to manually refresh the page? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive done some more reading and i think this is the way its supposed to work. If you open a website from a shortcut (havn't tried it without), if the manifest file has changed then the files are recached but the changes are only shown the **next** time the page is seen.

It appears you can force a refresh with javascript. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html